# How to say "To end" when the verb is not a simple V + O

Tags: grammar

I know that there are some basic ways to say " to end" with a common Verb + Object pair. (ex. 吃完饭。 开完会， 等） But， what if it is a verb like 培训？  Or if it is a noun form of 培训 ？

Would you say “培训完成以后？“ or is there a better way to say this?

Comment: 培完训 will do perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Just put 完 at the end of the verb will do the job. Examples are as follows:

> 培训完之后，我们去吃饭吧！
>
> 锻炼完之后，我们去吃饭吧！
>
> 冥想完之后，我们去吃饭吧！
>
> 蹲起完之后，我们去吃饭吧！